# Apache Solr Master-Repeater-Slave failover setup

Tags: solr, replication, failover, master-slave

Our development team is currently exploring architecture for standalone Solr instances in a Master-Repeater-Slave setup. The requirement is to make the setup highly available with the least amount of manual intervention. We also want a secondary master in case the primary master goes down i.e the indexing requests shouldn't be affected. Some downtime with search queries is acceptable. Primary master can handle both search and indexing queries. Our search and indexing traffic is not huge at the moment.

We don't want to use Solr Cloud.

We want some clarity for the following scenarios -

1. Is it possible to have master-master setup using only Solr configurations, where all the instances act as master and handle search & indexing queries? And also the replication between all masters is handled automatically.
   Based on our research we found out that this is not possible and we need one dedicated master in the setup.
2. If the above is not possible, what is the best approach to handle master failover so that indexing queries are not affected. Please provide details on how to handle replication and how to keep the primary master in sync when it comes back online.

We tried a master-master setup with 2 instances where both the instances were acting as a repeater. But the bi-directional replication was not happening automatically.

Comment: When you start talking about master-master with bi-directional replication you're effectively trying to reimplement SolrCloud functionality (which will send the updates to all nodes that have relevant shards for a specific collection). In general, when you want to go down this route, you're going to reimplement a lot of what SolrCloud gives you. Solr isn't well-suited for replication in a multi master setup, since replication happens _on the index file level_, so it's the actual files being replicated, not updates. Which means: one server is the reference server, and all files get replicated

Comment: from that single node. You could possibly do multi indexing support by having multiple masters that have separate shards of the index, and then replicate these shards as cores to all nodes, so that you effectively combine two indexes as one when searching - so regardless of which of the two nodes (shards) received the indexing request, it was at least stored in one of the two shards. But again, you're still replicating the built-in functionality in SolrCloud. The cloud / cluster functionality was designed to be the answer to what you want.

Comment: Scores are also calculated shard-wise, so you'll generally want to distribute your documents about evenly-ish across the available shards.